# Argument of complex number: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find $\arg z$ where
> $$z=-\frac{i\omega-w_0}{i\omega+w_0}$$
> where $\omega$ and $\omega_0$ are positive numbers.

My attempt was this:

$$\arg z=\pi +\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{-\omega_0}\right)+\pi-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)$$$$=2\pi -\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)$$$$=2\pi-2\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)$$

However, the correct answer seems to be:
$$\arg z =\pi-2\arctan\left(\frac{\omega}{\omega_0}\right)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Take $\omega=\omega_0=1$, then $z=-i$. Which answer is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misunderstood concepts.
$$\arg(z_1\pm z_2)\neq \arg z_1\pm \arg z_2$$
The proper and intended way would be to write $z$ in the form $a+bi$. This can be done as follows:
$$z=\frac{\omega_0-i\omega}{\omega_0+i\omega}=\frac{(\omega_0-i\omega)(\omega_0-i\omega)}{(\omega_0+i\omega)(\omega_0-i\omega)}$$
$$z=\frac{\omega_0^2-\omega^2-2\omega_0\omega i}{\omega_0^2+\omega^2}$$
$$z=\frac{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}{\omega_0^2+\omega^2}+\frac{-2\omega_0\omega}{\omega_0^2+\omega^2}i$$
And with this, we can easily calculate $\arg z$.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. However I don't think I'm applying the property you mentioned, but rather $$\arg(z_1\times z_2)= \arg z_1+ \arg z_2$$ and $$\arg(z_1/ z_2)= \arg z_1- \arg z_2$$. Isn't this correct?

Comment: @GrangerObliviate: Can you then elaborate how you found the argument for numerator?